# Clearing Siri Shortcuts doesn't fully work

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirishortcuts

In my App I have some shortcuts that need to be deleted and recreated since are associated to IDs that might change.

I'm calling:

`INVoiceShortcutCenter.shared.setShortcutSuggestions([])`

but even calling this, I see that my previous shortcuts are always available in the Apple Shortcuts app and in user settings under the Siri & Search section.

It sounds more like a bug and I will fill a radar but I wanted to have your point of view on this. Should the shortcuts be removed from Shortcuts apps and Siri & Search after calling setShortcutSuggestions with an empy array right? is this the intended behavior?